# Android dynamically added views won't use style

Tags: java, android, themes

I spent the last day figuring out my error but I can't find it...
I have an activity without any content, it is loaded dynamically later.

manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.marcel.recipes">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".emptyActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

While my mainActivity uses all the wanted colors, my emptyActivity ignores them.
The activity contains checkboxes and a TextView, which both have the textcolors #000000 and the checkbox gets the color #80CBC4 when I click it.

When I add Views with the designer, the colors are loading as wanted, but not for the dynamically added ones.

Comment: sorry,I can't get your problem,please explain your current problem and what you want more clearly.

Comment: @FireSun the views that are added dynamically doesn't use the colors that are set by my styles.xml when I add them. Views that I added via designer/xml use the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View defined on xml layout can use your custom style is because when system inflate your layout xml,it will extract this value and apply them for your views,but when you create views use java code dynamically it won't,so you should use java code to extract this value in your style file and set this value for your view.

Comment: could you give me an example to do that on a checkbox? I can easily set the textColor, but how do I set the Color of the checkbox itself?

Comment: you mean checkbox icon color?

Comment: Yes, the color which the box with the marker in it gets